# Extra Decimal Places on Fuzion Token 'Latest Membership Fee'

Tags: civimail, tokens

Sending a Civimail built with Mosaico utilizing Fuzion Token 1.5 {latestcurrentmembership.allfee}

The amount should be $69.00 on a test record but the email reads:
69.000000000

Any suggestions? Was this the fix? Doesn't seem to be working here? https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/commit/8008a9fb36d3bae6bbe077540c7e22fddb3dabef

Update: classical Civimail does it too. Our localization settings are English, USD. Monetary Amount Display: %c %a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try applying the patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken/pull/41.patch)? If it worked please comment the [PR](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civitoken/pull/41) your test result for it to get merged.

Comment: This resolved the issue, thanks. I was poking around in that file but was not sure what to do.

Comment: Aren't super easy fixes and patches fun? I imagine people love squashing them early on as a confidence boost for the day.